# Regex pattern to match pattern except some string in it

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regex for some patttern.

```
/web/surfer* --Match
/web/surfer/information* --Not Match
```

Can some one tell how do we write Regex pattern to match this in Java

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Here * means any text.

Comment: Why is it no match? Because of the third / or because of the word information? Or due to length?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. * means any text. It may or may not contain /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for negative lookahead like this regex:

```
/web/surfer(?!/information).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
String s = "/web/surfer/information";
System.out.println(s.matches("/web/surfer(?!/information).*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^/web/surfer(?>[^i]++|\\Bi|i(?!nformation\\b))*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is that you're using * to match any text whereas you actually need a dot instead.

Would this help?

```
    String regex = "/web/surfer.*";
    System.out.println("/web/surfer*".matches(regex));  // prints true
    System.out.println("/web/surfer/information*".matches(regex)); // prints true
```